# Why does my program not return the proper file information?

Tags: google-apps-script

**What I want to do:** Read text from pdf files in a specific folder. There are multiple PDF files in this folder, and I have to loop through them to retrieve the text from each. 
**Problem I am having:** My program is not getting the proper `File` information, and it is returning an error `Invalid Argument`. The error message is just this. 
 
**Language:** Google Apps Script

**My code:**

```
//Folder ID
var myFolderID = "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX";

/**
Get PDF files from the folder and return them in an array
*/ 
function GetPdfFiles(){
    var pdfFiles = [];
    var files = DriveApp.getFolderById(myFolderID).getFiles();
    while(files.hasNext())
    {
         var file = files.next();
         //retrieve only pdf files (non-pdf files need to be ignored)
         if(file.getName().indexOf("pdf") >= 1)
         {
             //Add to the array the file data
             pdfFiles.push(file);
         }
    }
    return pdfFiles;
}

/**
Do some operations to each PDF file 
*/
function DoSomeOperations(pdfFiles){

    for(var i = 0; i < pdfFiles.length; i++)
    {
        //The below line of code doesn't work
        var doc = DocumentApp.openByUrl(pdfFiles[i].getUrl());   /*Error*/
        //I also tried the below code instead of the above line of code
        var doc = DocumentApp.openById(pdfFiles[i].getId());     /*Error*/


        /*Ideally, do some operation to each PDF file here */
        /*I was hoping to use something like this: */
        var textFromPdfFile = doc.getBody().getText();
        /*But I cannot get this "doc" in the first place.*/
    }
}

function Main(){
    var pdfFiles = GetPdfFiles();
    DoSomeOperations(pdfFiles);
}
```

Can someone tell me what I am doing wrong?

**Edit:** I logged "getID" and "getUrl" result, and it is showing the result. But it seems like it is not the actual ID or URL... I don't know what is going on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- You want to retrieve the text from PDF files using `doc.getBody().getText()`.
- The mimeType of PDF file is `application/pdf`.
- You want to achieve this using Google Apps Script.

If my understanding is correct, how about this modification? Please think of this as just one of several answers.

#### Modification points:

- Unfortunately, in the current stage, the PDF file cannot be directly opened with `DocumentApp.openByUrl()` and `DocumentApp.openById()`. In this case, at first, the PDF file is required to be converted to Google Document. By this, it can be opened with `DocumentApp.openByUrl()` and `DocumentApp.openById()`.

#### Modified script:

In this modified script, the method of Files: copy of Drive API is used. So before you use this script, [please enable Drive API at Advanced Google services.](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/advanced#enabling_advanced_services)

```
//Folder ID
var myFolderID = "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX";

/**
Get PDF files from the folder and return them in an array
*/ 
function GetPdfFiles(){
    var pdfFiles = [];
    var files = DriveApp.getFolderById(myFolderID).getFiles();
    while(files.hasNext())
    {
         var file = files.next();
         //retrieve only pdf files (non-pdf files need to be ignored)
         if (file.getMimeType() == MimeType.PDF) { // Check the mimeType.
             // Convert PDF file to Google Document
             var id = Drive.Files.copy({mimeType: MimeType.GOOGLE_DOCS}, file.getId()).id;
             //Add to the array the file data
             pdfFiles.push(id);
         }
    }
    return pdfFiles;
}

/**
Do some operations to each PDF file 
*/
function DoSomeOperations(pdfFiles){

    for(var i = 0; i < pdfFiles.length; i++)
    {
        //The below line of code doesn't work
        // var doc = DocumentApp.openByUrl(pdfFiles[i].getUrl()); // This is not used.
        //I also tried the below code instead of the above line of code
        var doc = DocumentApp.openById(pdfFiles[i]);


        /*Ideally, do some operation to each PDF file here */
        /*I was hoping to use something like this: */
        var textFromPdfFile = doc.getBody().getText();
        /*But I cannot get this "doc" in the first place.*/

        // Drive.Files.remove(pdfFiles[i]); // If you want to delete the converted file, please use this line.
    }
}

function Main(){
    var pdfFiles = GetPdfFiles();
    DoSomeOperations(pdfFiles);
}
```

#### References:

- [Advanced Google services](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/advanced)
- [Files: copy](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v2/reference/files/copy)

If I misunderstood your question and this was not the direction you want, I apologize.

### Edit:

- You want to convert PDF file to Google Document when the the filename of converted Google Document is not existing.

If my understanding is correct, how about this modification? Please modify above my script as follows.

#### Pattern 1:

Did you use this line of `Drive.Files.remove(pdfFiles[i]);` in my above script? When this line is used, the converted Google Document is always deleted. In this case, the Google Document files with the same filename are not created. How about this?

#### Pattern 2:

If you don't want to use `Drive.Files.remove(pdfFiles[i]);`, how about the following modification? Please modify the function of `GetPdfFiles()` as follows. By this modification, when the same filename of Google Document is existing, the PDF file is not converted.

From:

```
// Convert PDF file to Google Document
var id = Drive.Files.copy({mimeType: MimeType.GOOGLE_DOCS}, file.getId()).id;
//Add to the array the file data
pdfFiles.push(id);
```

To:

```
var existingFile = DriveApp.getFilesByName(file.getName().split(".")[0]);
if (!(existingFile.hasNext() && existingFile.next().getMimeType() == MimeType.GOOGLE_DOCS)) {
  // Convert PDF file to Google Document
  var id = Drive.Files.copy({mimeType: MimeType.GOOGLE_DOCS}, file.getId()).id;
  //Add to the array the file data
  pdfFiles.push(id);
}
```

Comment: I believe the `DoSomeOperations(pdfFiles)` function should be written like this:`function DoSomeOperations(pdfFiles){
  for(var i=0;i<pdfFiles.length;i++) {
    var doc = DocumentApp.openById(pdfFiles[i]);
    var textFromPdfFile = doc.getBody().getText();
  }
}` The pdfFiles array now has ids in it and not files.

Comment: @Cooper Oh. Yes. I had miss-copied. Thank you for your support.

Comment: @Tanaike-san, Thanks! While testing many times, I had created so many copies of google documents with the same file name. Is there any way to create a copy only if it doesn't already exist? I thought .HasNext() could be used, but I am not sure how to integrate this in this while loop.

Comment: @J.Doe Thank you for replying. About your new issue, although I would like to support you, I cannot understand about `Is there any way to create a copy only if it doesn't already exist?`? Can I ask you about the detail situation of it? When I could see the vision of your goal, I can think of the solution. But I deeply apologize for my poor English skill.

Comment: @Tanaike-san, いえ、丁寧に回答していただきありがとうございます。本回答をしていただいた中で、var id = Drive.Files.copy({mimeType: MimeType.GOOGLE_DOCS}, file.getId()).id; と書かれていますが、これはPDFのコピーをGoogle Documentで生成しているのだと思います。しかし、何度かプログラムを流した後フォルダを確認すると、同じ名前のGoogle Docsのコピーが大量生成されていました。そこで、できることであればこのコピー生成の箇所は、もしすでに同じ名前のGoogle Documentが存在しない場合のみに限定できないかなと思ったのです。あくまでテストの段階なのですが、いかがでしょうか？知恵をお貸しいただければ幸いです。

Comment: @J.Doe 目標を理解できたかもしれません。Thank you for replying. For your new issue, I added the modified script. Could you please confirm it? If this was not the result you want, I apologize.

Comment: @J.Doe Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved. 無事解決できたとのことで安心しました。こちらこそご協力頂き有難うございました。